# Overridden methods and dynamic binding

Tags: java, overriding, dynamic-binding

Is there a possibility for an overridden method to be resolved statically?

And what is the relation between Invoke virtual and dynamic binding? Are all invoke virtual methods dynamically bound?

```
class Dynamic
{
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("in dynamic");
    }
    public static void invoke(Dynamic x)
    {
        x.display();
    }
}
```

here x.display shows invoke virtual? what does it mean?does it mean it is dynamically bound?

Comment: What do you want to achieve and which *concrete* coding problems did you stumble upon?

Comment: in java there is no virtual method concept.

Comment: Was just doing some research,and stumbled on this topic,where someone wrote this code without extending another class,and on parsing it showed invoke virtual,and said even this is dynamically bind

Comment: @Rustam its a bytecode, you have invoke static,virtual ,invokespecial as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Overriden methods cannot be resolved at compile time. They are resolved during *Runtime* based on type of object.

`InvokeVirtual` is the Byte-code way of telling you that a method has been called.

Comment: SO why there is 4 different ways? invoke static,invoke special,invoke virtual and invoke interface?

Comment: @curositykiller - invoke static is for *static methods* `String.valueO()`, *invoke Specia* is for *constructors* , *invoke virtual* is for any non-static method (SOP).

Comment: so invoke virtual doesn't have to do anything with dynamic binding?

Comment: @curositykiller - Not necessarily. Even if you call a normal method, you will *Invoke Virtual* will be present in the byte code.